# Raster in QGIS with Python: blank window

Tags: raster, pyqgis, fedora

I'm trying to learn to write QGIS Python Applications. To start with something simple, I thought I'd try to write an application to open a raster layer in QGIS. Here is the code:

```
import os

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

print "Qgis initialised"

window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window_frame = QtGui.QFrame(window)
window.setCentralWidget(window_frame)
frame_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(window_frame)

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
frame_layout.addWidget(canvas)

filename = 'filepath'
fileinfo = QFileInfo(filename)
path = fileinfo.filePath()
basename = fileinfo.baseName()

if fileinfo.exists():
    print "raster exists"

if QgsRasterLayer.isValidRasterFileName(path, "unknown"):
    print "File is a valid raster"
else:
    print "File is not a valid raster"

layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, basename)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
canvas_layer = QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)
canvas.setLayerSet([canvas_layer])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()

if layer.isValid() is True:
    print "Layer working"
else:
    print "Layer is not working"

window.show()
print "window shown"

QgsApplication.exitQgis()

app.exec_()
print "app executed"
```

This is the output when I run it:

```
Qgis initialised
raster exists
File is a valid raster
Layer working
window shown
```

and a window does open, but it remains blank. The filepath is correct, if I simply write in the bash console:

```
qgis filepath
```

qgis opens it correctly. I've tried changing the canvas color:

```
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.yellow)
```

and it works; it's just the image that doesn't appear.

I don't understand if it's a code problem or a system problem. My Linux distribution is Fedora 23.

Comment: Is your colormap set correctly? Almost all my display problems in QGIS stem from incorrect color mapping. When you drag the raster into QGIS, does it display correctly?